# Unused import statement when using Selenium in Intellij

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea

Sometimes I see an error message showing "unused import statement". But all things is working normally when I'm trying to debug or inspect code. I can fix this by move all codes into new class with the same name and delete the old error class. It's not a big deal but sometimes makes me feel annoyed. Restart IDE or refresh dependency has no affect with this. How can I resolve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this class `AllPostsPage` exists in your project? Also, package names start with lowercase letters in Java.

Comment: omg, I figured out where is the error, also named package start with an uppercase letter is my bad. Great thanks to you.